# How to make Tkinter.Button responsive to both <Return> and a button click simultaneously?

Tags: python, tkinter

**The Problem**

I'm writing a really basic GUI for issuing sql commands to a sqlite3 database with the python API. The features of the GUI include a `load database` button, an entry widget that displays the path to the database, an `SQL command` entry widget and an enter button. My problem is with trying to bind the `<return>` to the SQL Entry widget. I want be able to optionally to press the `<Return>` key or the `Enter` button, to enter process the command. How do you do this?

**My Code:**

```
import Tkinter
import sqlite3
import tkFileDialog

class SQLCommand(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.init_gui()
        self.geometry('400x200')

        self.mainloop()

    def init_gui(self):
        self.frameM=Tkinter.Frame(self,relief='ridge').pack(side=Tkinter.TOP)
        Tkinter.Button(self.frameM,relief='ridge',text='Load Database',command=self.load).pack(side=Tkinter.TOP,fill=Tkinter.X)
        self.filename_entry=Tkinter.StringVar(self)
        Tkinter.Entry(self.frameM,textvariable=self.filename_entry).pack(side=Tkinter.TOP,fill=Tkinter.X)
        self.frameL=Tkinter.Frame(self,relief='ridge').pack(side=Tkinter.TOP,fill=Tkinter.X)
        Tkinter.Label(self.frameL,text='SQL Command:').pack(side=Tkinter.TOP,fill=Tkinter.X)#,text='Insert SQL Command').pack(Tkinter.TOP)

        self.frameE=Tkinter.Frame(self,relief='ridge').pack(side=Tkinter.TOP,fill=Tkinter.X)
        self.Evar=Tkinter.StringVar(self.frameE)
        Tkinter.Entry(self.frameE,textvariable=self.Evar).pack(side=Tkinter.TOP,fill=Tkinter.X)


        self.frameB=Tkinter.Frame(self,relief='solid').pack(side=Tkinter.TOP,fill=Tkinter.X)
        self.B=Tkinter.Button(self.frameB,text='Enter',command=self.enter)
        self.B.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP,fill=Tkinter.X)
        self.bind('<Return>',self.enter)

    def load(self):
        self.database_filename=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        self.filename_entry.set(self.database_filename)
        self.conn=DataBase(self.database_filename).conn

    def enter(self,event):
        with self.conn as c:
            cur=c.cursor()
            cur.execute(self.Evar.get())
            print cur.fetchone()
```

**The Error When Return key Pressed**

[image]

But the `Enter` button is fully operational

Comment: Use `None` as default value `def enter(self, event=None):`

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command=self.button` executes it without arguments as `self.enter()` but `bind(..., self.enter)` executes it with one argument as `self.enter(event)`

You can set default value for `event` to work with both method, ie.

```
def enter(self, event=None):
```